# Outlook 2013 make a default email recipient

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there any way to make a **default email recipient** in Outlook 2013? For instance, I want to click `New Email`and the `To...` is automatically populated with this person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

What however is possible is to make a quick step. you can make a new quick step to create a new e-mail message to a specific recipient.

More about it here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automate-common-or-repetitive-tasks-with-Quick-Steps-a9caf57e-0eb0-4b48-9141-a9904da0aaf9

**Create a Quick Step**

1. In **Mail**, on the **Home tab**, in the **Quick Steps group**, in the Quick Steps gallery, click the **Create New Quick Step**.
2. Click an action type from the list or click **Custom**.
3. In the Name box, type a name for the new Quick Step.
4. Click the icon button next to the Name box, click an icon, and then click **OK**.
5. Under **Actions**, choose an action that you want the Quick Step to do. Click **Add Action** for any additional actions.
6. To create a keyboard shortcut, in the Shortcut key box, click the keyboard shortcut that you want to assign.